# Perturbation of steady solutions to a non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, perturbation-theory

I would appreciate if someone could please help me clarify this problem.

Given the system of equations
$\frac{dx}{dt}=-4x+y+x^2$, $\frac{dy}{dy}=\frac{3}{2}\alpha-y$, where $\alpha$ is an arbitrary constant, we can find the two steady solutions to be: $(2+\sqrt{4-\frac{3}{2}\alpha}, \frac{3}{2}\alpha)$ and $(2-\sqrt{4-\frac{3}{2}\alpha}, \frac{3}{2}\alpha)$.

Now I need to perturb the steady solutions but I'm completely lost here since I don't know what exactly needs to be achieved. Does one remove square roots via perturbation or what? The aim is to then linearize the system with the perturbed steady solutions.

Comment: Take $x = x_{\rm SS} + \delta x$ and $y = y_{\rm SS} + \delta y$ and insert this into the equation. Expand in a Taylor series to first order in $\delta x,\delta y$ to get a linear equation system.

Comment: But if we substitute $x=2+\sqrt{4-\frac{3}{2}\alpha}+\delta x$ into the equation, we will get $0 = -4(2+\sqrt{4-\frac{3}{2}\alpha})+\frac{3}{2}\alpha+(2+\sqrt{4-\frac{3}{2}\alpha})^2$. Is this the correct way to do?

Comment: If you do it for the $x$-eqaution you get: $\frac{d\delta x}{dt} = -4x_{\rm SS} + y_{\rm SS} + (x_{\rm SS} + \delta x_{\rm SS})^2 - 4\delta x + \delta y$. To simplify use that $(x_{\rm SS} + \delta x_{\rm SS})^2 = x_{\rm SS}^2 + 2x_{\rm SS}\delta x + (\delta x)^2$ (the last term can be ignored since it's second order) and to simplfy even further note that the definition of the steady state solution implies $-4x_{\rm SS} + y_{\rm SS} + x_{\rm SS}^2 = 0$.

Comment: Can you please clarify why $(\delta x)^2$ can be ignored?

Comment: Because of this "the aim is to then linearize the system". When we linearize we only keep the linear terms. This term is quadratic. It might be better to just keep it there when deriving the equation and then only remove it in the end when you linearize.

Comment: As the result, since there are two steady state solutions, does one get two systems of linear equations?

Comment: You have to do the analysis for both. However if you do it in general as I did above (i.e. not using the explicit form for $x_{\rm SS},y_{\rm SS}$) when deriving and then solving the ODE then the final solution you get applies for both fix-points (and you can then substitute in the specific form for $x_{\rm SS},y_{\rm SS}$ to determine if each fixpoint is stable/unstable).